# Use emscripten webassembly threads (C++) with webpack (create-react-app)

Tags: multithreading, webpack, create-react-app, webassembly, emscripten

I have an emscripten/webassembly wrapped C++ class that launches and uses pthreads internally.  It generally works fine when used in javascript on Chrome in its stand-alone development sandbox.  However, I can't really get it to work with create-react-app and webpack (i.e. I used react-app-rewired to be able to configure webpack).

The problem seems to be from the complexity of the javascript and wasm files that a threaded emscripten build creates, and the confusion those scripts have due to the renaming of files that webpack produces.  The files produced for a multi-threaded emscipten build are:

```
MyModule.js
MyModule.wasm
MyModule.worker.js
```

I can (I think) get it to work in the non-threaded mode where there is just a `MyModule.js` and a `MyModule.wasm` file through the use of the `Module`'s `locateFile` method.  However, the system gets very confused due to the introduction of the new `MyModule.worker.js` file which the `MyModule.js` file launches on its own within a WebWorker.  And of course the `MyModule.worker.js` file needs to also find and get access to `MyModule.wasm`, and that gets lost too (i.e. can't find the right file name due to the webpack renaming).

Anyway, I've spent hours searching the web for any successful use cases like this, and trying may things, including manually editing the `MyModule.js` and `MyModule.worker.js` files, but without any luck so far.

Has anyone successfully tried something like this, or any other advice on getting a multi-threaded emscripten/wasm build to run properly with webpack (or create-react-app)?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: This question isn't about running a emscripten/webassembly module in a web-worker thread (although in the end I'm going to run all this in a web-worker).  Its specifically about a multi-threaded emscripten build (i.e. C++ with pthreads) launching and running properly with webpack.

Answer (score 0):

In Module's locateFile, you should return the correct path for MyModule.wasm and MyModule.worker.js.
Besides, In Module's mainScriptUrlOrBlob, you should assign the path for MyModule.js.
The mainScriptUrlOrBlob is used in worker for loading the wasm.